# New bathroom design - stack pipe

Tags: bathroom, pipe, drain-waste-vent

I am trying to add a new bathroom in the attic for kids.

Here is idea 1, my doubt is that could I join the toilet drain into the laundry drain? Does that cause any issues like the smell?

I am new to DIY but would like to learn new things. I believe that the laundry rain pipe and main stack pipe would be connected somewhere in the ground of the basement. I plan to take hot and cold water lines also from the laundry room to the attic.

Please help with any insights or ask me any questions for clarification.

[image: My rough diagram of the plan]

Comment: What size is the "laundry room pipe" and what is now connected to it / what do your propose to add to it? Proper traps and venting deal with smells, but verifying adequate capacity is a concern.

Comment: Hi, laundry room pipe is 4 inches wide and presently have laundry machine's drain only.